# I'm attempting to use jquery ui (accordion) inside an AnythingSlider panel and it's not working - somebody look?

Tags: jquery-ui, anythingslider

I'm making a site from AnythingSlider and want to use jQuery UI's accordion feature inside a panel and the whole page poops the bed. All of the references to js and css work. And now for the news...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  // Set up Sliders
  // **************
  $(function(){
   $('#slider').anythingSlider({
    startPanel             : 1,
    buildArrows     : false, 
    autoPlay               : false,
    width                   : 600,   // if resizeContent is false, this is the default width if panel size is not defined
    height                  : 350,   // if resizeContent is false, this is the default height if panel size is not defined
    resizeContents        : false, // If true, solitary images/objects in the panel will expand to fit the viewport
    startStopped          : true,  // If autoPlay is on, this can force it to start stopped
    navigationFormatter  : function(index, panel){ // Format navigation labels with text
     return ['home', 'menu', 'find us', 'order online', 'cater', 'contact'][index - 1];
    }
   });

   $("#accordion").accordion({ header: "h3" });

  });
 </script>
```

And in the body:

```
<li class="panel2">

  <div id="accordion">
   <div>
    <h3><a href="#">First</a></h3>
    <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>
   </div>
   <div>
    <h3><a href="#">Second</a></h3>
    <div>Phasellus mattis tincidunt nibh.</div>
   </div>
   <div>
    <h3><a href="#">Third</a></h3>
    <div>Nam dui erat, auctor a, dignissim quis.</div>
   </div>
  </div>
    </li>
```

Answer (score 1):

What's missing is a CSS definition to set your panel2 height. Because initially it's just a list, the height is much smaller. But when you convert it into an accordion, the height grows. I can't think of an easier method, so probably it's best to figure out the height you want:

```
.panel2 { height: 350px; }
```

Here is a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/FVVLg/).

Also note that if I set `resizeContents: true` in the demo, I don't need that bit of CSS above.

Comment: I'd already declared a height in the css, which I didn't think to include in the question, but here's the declaration for the panels inside class=slider:#slider .panel1       { width: 1000px; height: 400px; }
#slider .panel2       { width: 1000px; height: 400px; } 
#slider .panel3       { width: 1000px; height: 400px; }
#slider .panel4       { width: 1000px; height: 400px; }
#slider .panel5       { width: 1000px; height: 400px; }
#slider .panel6       { width: 1000px; height: 400px; } - and still doesn't work. Here's the URL: bigsilkdesign.com/mercado/index_jquery_ui.html

Answer (score 0):

My stupid, stupid bad. It works. I neglected to add something as a result of copy and pasting into a new doc.  If you're interested: http://bigsilkdesign.com/mercado/

Thank you, though, for your response. For that, you get a one up. Not like you need it, but credit where due.

If for nothing else, to see my altered use of AnythingSlider...

Comment: broken link, can you fix it?